# ibm cloud private space issue on docker devmapper

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I got the following error.

`devmapper: Thin Pool has 82984 free data blocks which is less than minimum required 163840 free data blocks. Create more free space in thin pool or use dm.min_free_space option to change behavior`

Can someone assist?

Answer (score 0):

We did tests at our Lab environment and we applied the solution at docker site, https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/#increase-capacity-on-a-running-device topic Resize a direct-lvm thin pool, and it solved the issue.

I did not extended the LV thinpool during the problem at PROD, what caused the impression that the resolution was very difficult, but I just executed the lvextend -l+100%FREE -n docker/thinpool and docker recognize the new space available and back to create containers without problem.